# How to compare 2 strings until a certain point each?

Tags: java

I need to compare 2 different strings with each other. I have `String a` and `String b`. `String a` holds a long string while `String b` tries to copy it via the users typing. `String a` is much larger than b. Is there a way to do this efficiently? So far the way i thought of it was for every button press it would run something along these lines of code.

```
splitTextA = fullTextA.substring(0, String b length ); 
if (splitText ==  String B)
   change String change to a color green
else if false 
   change string change to a color red
```

A couple things, I dont know how to get the length of a string, i know how to split it though. and do you think this would work?

ps: sorry I dont know how to separate lines of code
this is not hw.. this is on my own Im just practicing.

Comment: `String.equals("another string");` not `String == String1`. Length of a String: `String.length()`

Comment: What does `String a color green` mean?

Comment: Look up the `startsWith` method in the Javadoc.

Comment: I have feeling that the [Open letter to students with homework problems](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems) applies here.